# angular2 `ngControlGroup` inside a child component

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a form that looks like this in the template

```
<form [ngFormModel]="form">
  <div ngControlGroup="contents">
    <div ngControlGroup="title">
      <div *ngFor="let lang of languages$ | async" [ngControlGroup]="lang">
        <md-input ngControl="content"></md-input>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

and the shape looks like this

```
this.form = this.builder.group({
  contents: this.builder.group({
    title: this.builder.group({
      en: this.builder.group({
        id: this.builder.control(null),
        content: this.builder.control('some english content')
      }),
      cs: this.builder.group({
        id: this.builder.control(null),
        content: this.builder.control('some czech content')
      })
    })
  })
});
```

and I would like to put the

```
<div ngControlGroup="contents">
  <div ngControlGroup="title">
    <div *ngFor="let lang of languages | async" [ngControlGroup]="lang"><!--  --></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

part into a component, that would look like this

```
<form-contents-item type="title" [languages]="languages$ | async">
  <md-input ngControl="content"></md-input>
</form-contents-item>
```

and its template like this

```
<div ngControlGroup="contents">
  <!-- `title` from @Input -->
  <div [ngControlGroup]="title">
    <!-- `languages` from @Input -->
    <div *ngFor="let lang of languages" [ngControlGroup]="lang">
      <!-- content projection here, probably using `ngTemplateOutlet`, since you can't iterate over ng-content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the problem is, that `ngControlGroup` needs to be child of either `ngForm` or `ngFormModel`, and so does `ngControl` on that input that I will project with `template`. So the question is, how can I possibly make this work? Share the `form` instance to my `form-contents-item`, would probably only work for the group, not for the input itself? So something else?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a normal component an make it compatible with `ngModel` by implementing `ControlValueAccessor`.

Comment: I'm not quite seeing how's that going to help :/ I can make a component compatible with `ngModel` alright, but that only works for `ngControl`, not `ngControlGroup`, right? So which part is this going to solve?

Comment: What's the purpose of having the component as controlgroup? I don't think that is supported.

Comment: I don't need component as a ControlGroup, I just don't want to make that bit with `ngControlGroup="contents"` and `ngControlGroup="title"` and `ngFor` DRY, since the only thing that would change is the "title". So I thought I'd make a component, pass it the "title" part and be done with it. But that wouldn't work because `ngControlGroup` needs to be child of `ngForm`.

Comment: So what do you need the control groups for. I'm not too experienced with forms in Angular2.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and what I had to do was to set the controlGroup on the child component, access the control group via constructor injection in the child component but also set the `ngFormModel` in the template.

Parent template :

```
<form-contents-item [ngControlGroup]="content" type="title" [languages]="languages$ | async">
  <md-input ngControl="content"></md-input>
</form-contents-item>
```

Child template:

```
<div [ngFormModel]="contents">
      <!-- `title` from @Input -->
      <div [ngControlGroup]="title">
        <!-- `languages` from @Input -->
        <div *ngFor="let lang of languages" [ngControlGroup]="lang">
          <!-- content projection here, probably using `ngTemplateOutlet`, since you can't iterate over ng-content -->
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Edit: `contents` would be the property name that is assigned the injected `controlGroup` in `form-contents-item`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing, but that only solves first part of the problem, the other being when you try to use `<ng-content>` or `[ngTemplateOutlet]`, that breaks the "binding" as well.